# Laravel 405 error + no api methods in artisan routes:list

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have an error when calling for POST requests through API.

If I calling `put method` through web.php than everything works fine, however when I request PUT(POST) method via api.php - I have 405 error:

```
"405 Method Not Allowed"
```

Moreover if I put command `php artisan routes:list`  in a console I could see solely routes which are placed in web.php file. If I, for example, clean web.php I see an empty routes:list despite the fact that api.php file is full.

`Get requests` from api.php are processing well.

api.php route file:

```
<?php

use Dingo\Api\Routing\Router;

$router = app(Router::class);

$router->version('v1', function(Router $router){

  $router->group(['namespace'=>'App\Http\Controllers'], function(Router $router){

      $router->post('test', 'PostController@store');

  });    

});
```

Comment: If you are sending requests through HTML, you need use [method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing). If you do not see routes that are defined in api.php in the console (`art route:lis`) you need to check [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L36-L43). Good Luck.

Comment: @Kyslik Thank you for your support. Could I manually check PUT/POST request through Postman?

Comment: Yea requests sent via Postman should work as *expected* (without the spoofing).

Comment: @Kyslik But they have the same status:     "message": "405 Method Not Allowed",
    "status_code": 405 when I calling through Postman too. I have checked RouteServiceProvider and I have exact the same file as placed in repository. But I can't see PUT/POST api routes.

Comment: If you are sending POST, you need to define a route as `Route::post(...)` if you are sending (or want to send) PUT you need to define a route as `Route::put(...)`. Obviously something is wrong here, with your api.php; you should paste it here. You can not expect me nor anyone else to guess the contents of the file where the problem is...

Comment: @Kyslik Sure, but both are not processing in my case.

Comment: @Kyslik I have done.

Comment: Excellent, where in the original body is dingo/api mentioned? Wow, I am amazed. Next time include all details from the beginning. Anyway, please do consult [dingo wiki](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Installation), from step 1 to 3. I can tell you now, if you can not figure this out yourself, you do not need dingo/api at all. Just stick to pure Laravel or take a look at [spatie's packages](https://github.com/spatie) instead, that may guide you. I am frank in order to help you in the long run. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Kyslik, Thank you for spatie's packages reference. Wish you also Good luck in all of your projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such issue could happens if you request your route in Postman through a GET request. Please check it careful if it is not your issue.

Comment: Indeed. I have tried to call this request through an wrong type. Thank you for a support, I will be more careful next time.

Comment: @vppy this is clearly not an answer to OP question. OP uses dingo/api and OP did not register or install it properly thus, when using it in api.php Laravel did not register the routes. It would be better suited as comment instead.